# String formatting: optional section

Tags: python, string, format

I have the following string format:

```
string = "{part1}_{part2}_{part3}"
```

I want to format the string by setting the different parts to different values.
The catch is that part2 is optional. So I can't do the following, because it would leave me with a duplicate underscore:

```
result = string.format(part1="A", part2="", part3="B")
actual_result = "A__B"
desired_result = "A_B"
```

I cannot replace all duplicate underscores by single ones afterwards because the strings I use to replace the parts may already contain duplicate underscores:

```
result = string.format(part1="A__A", part2="", part3="B__B")
result = result.replace("__", "_")
actual_result = "A_A_B_B"
desired_result = "A__A_B__B"
```

My solution looks like this, but I wonder if there is something more elegant.

```
ignore_str = "$IGNORE_STRING$"
string = "{part1}_{part2}_{part3}"

result = string.format(part1="A__A", part2=ignore_str, part3="B__B")    
result = result.replace("_" + ignore_str, "")
actual_result = "A__A_B__B"
```

I was kind of hoping that there was a cool `str.format()` trick I could apply. I know that I can write my own format classes but that seems to produce a lot more code and may become quite confusing for the reader.

I am looking for a solution that is pythonic, elegant and readable.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this with just `.format()`. You could come up with your own template language that you parse and replace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to make the underscore optional in Python 3. :)

```
spacer = "_" if part2 else ""
desired_result = f"{part1}_{part2}{spacer}{part3}"
```

Comment: Please explain why that code "could work" to solve the OP's issue. For long term value, quality posts, and upvotes, most answers should include an explanation, and caveats of the given code.

Comment: That's a cool idea, thanks! At the time of my writing I was still at an older version of Python that did not support the f-notation. This answer is not very readable though. If you re-format your answer to the more readable `f"{part1}_{part2}{'_' if part2 else ''}{part3}"`, I'll accept it

Comment: Could you also add an option that is even more readable by extracting the if/else part to a separate line, like this? `spacer = "_" if part2 else ""` I think that's the most readable version